# extracting the url/uri of the link

Tags: c#

after I load the HTML content in the web view using navigate function, and click on a link in HTML content I am not able to understand how to get the url of the link I am clicking on ?...I want to update the url in the address bar (text box) as I click on the link .. I even tried using this but still not getting the url

```
WebView1.LoadCompleted += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(load_Completed);


private void load_Completed(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   AddressBar.Text = WebView1.Source.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading [`e.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.uri) instead?

Comment: oh it worked...thank you so much ..how do i come to know if i have clicked the link ..actually i want to show my progress bar while i'm navigating ...

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest opening a new question on StackOverflow for that to attract attention from other contributors.